# Error interpreting CSV text delimiter in Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have comma separated csv files with Double quotes text delimiter:

Line12:

[image: Line 12]

[Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PegF5.png)

when I read the csv and put it in the data frame it does not correctly interpret the double quote:

Line 10:

[image: Line 10]

```
import os

import glob

import pandas as pd

path = r'\\Srvflssp03\gto\Planejamento_Operacional\Forecast\2021\11 Novembro\Relatórios MIS'

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '**/*.csv'), recursive=True)

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,quotechar = '"', sep = ',') for f in file_list ])

DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(combined_csv)

DataFrame.head(11)
```

how could I solve this and make the division by columns correct?

Comment: Instead of image from excel, please upload the first 12 lines from csv - the header and 11 data rows.

Comment: @buran I'm sorry but how can I do this without using excel? using some other program?

Comment: Open it in any editor like Notepad, Notepad++ or IDE like VSCode and copy/paste as text. Actually, because you don't import the csv properly in excel (i.e. each field in separate cell) you can copy/paste from excel (column A)

Comment: @buran thanks, i edited the post and inserted the image with the description Notepad++

Comment: We ask NOT to include images of code, data, etc. Copy/paste as text. With image we cannot test before we post solution. As you can see in the image this particular line is quoted as one big string.

Comment: @buran ok, but is there any way to treat this data so that it is in the desired format?

Comment: Date,Entity ID,Entity Name,Time,Contacts Recvd Revisado,Contacts Recvd Act,Contacts Handled Sched,Contacts Handled Access%,Contacts Abndn Act,Contacts Abndn Perc,AHT Revisado,AHT Act,Service Level Revisado,Service Level Act,Occupancy Revisado,Occupancy Act,ASA Revisado,ASA Act,Requirements Revisado,Requirements Act,Requirements +/-,Sched Open,Staff Est.,Staff - Req

"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the presence of a comma as the thousands separator for the digit '3,911.69'. 2 solutions: fix the problem upstream to generate a compatible csv for Pandas or create a custom function that cleans up these errors.

```
import re
import io

def clean_doublequotes(filename):
    """remove single double quotes but keep in case of double double quotes."""
    with open(filename) as fp:
        return io.StringIO(''.join([re.sub(r'"(?!")', '', line) for line in fp]))

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(clean_doublequotes(f), thousands=',')
                              for f in file_list])
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work. I put a new image in the post called Notepad++ see if it helps?

Comment: @FABRICIOFERREIRA. I updated my answer. Does it solve your problem now?